# How to get the sum of values in attributes in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get the sum. Here is the xslt code.

```
<xsl:template match="Entry">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10">


    <tr>
        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Value,'||')"/>
        </td>

        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')"/>

        </td>
    </tr>

</xsl:if>


    </xsl:template>
```

above code will fillter data as two coloums. It is ok. Now I need to get the sum of `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')"/>`

I am from procedural programming. I read many articles but I still coudnt figure out that how to get the sum of this. can anybody help me?

Here is the xml

```
<TopHoldings Currency="xxx">
          <Entry Type="CName||C||S||Fund Weight (%)||Benchmark weight (%)" Value="Ab||U||||1.2170000000000||" Date="8/31/2011" />
```

here is the whole xslt

```
        <table style="width:50%;font-size:12px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr style="width:50%; text-align:left;background-color:E6F1F9;">
            <th>       </th>
            <th>     % of funds     </th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates   select="$items">
                <xsl:sort select="format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(@Value,'||')"/> 
        </xsl:apply-templates>


        </table>

      </body>

    </html>

  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Entry">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10">


    <tr>
        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Value,'||')"/>
        </td>

        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')"/>

        </td>
    </tr>

</xsl:if>


    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you show us the template from which you are referring to this template?  Do you just want to sum the first 10 values?

Comment: yes I want to get the sum  of ten values

Comment: And regarding my request for a larger sample of your XSLT...? What processor are you using to execute your XSLT?

Comment: For the third time, ***would you show us some more of your XSLT***?

Comment: If there is only one entry line then you don't have anything to sum. Is there supposed to be more than one `entry` line in your xml? What values are you looking to sum?

Comment: I want to get sum of `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')"/>
`

Comment: @matthew yes there are hundreds of lines :D

Answer (score 2):

When you need to sum the values of multiple values on XSLT 1.0 you have to rely on recursion [EDIT: in XSLT 1.0 the function sum it is also available] (in XSLT 2.0 there is an XPath function sum()).

The following template performs the sum of the given elements through the elements-to-sum parameter, extracting the value to sum from the attribute @Value as you specified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="TopHoldings">
    <table>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum">
            <xsl:with-param name="elements-to-sum"
                            select="Entry" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum">
    <xsl:param name="elements-to-sum" />

    <xsl:param name="sum" select="'0'" />

    <!-- Store in variables the following operations to avoid performing them more than once -->
    <xsl:variable name="current-element" select="$elements-to-sum[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="current-value" select="format-number(substring(substring-after($current-element/@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')" />

    <!-- Output the table row -->
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($current-element/@Value, '||')" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$current-value" /></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Determine whether continue -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Case END: we have just one element to sum so we perform the sum and we output the desired result -->
        <xsl:when test="count($elements-to-sum) = 1">
            <tr>
                <td>Result:</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$current-value + $sum" /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Case RECURSION : we call this template again adding the current value to the sum and removing the first element from the parameter elements-to-sum -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="elements-to-sum"
                                select="$elements-to-sum[position() > 1]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum"
                                select="$sum + $current-value" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I assumed that you wanted to display the result of the sum as a new row in the same table, if that is not the case and you want to display the result elsewhere the solution would be slightly different. Tell me if this solution is acceptable to you or you need to display the sum outside the  element.

NOTE: Instead of doing those 'complex' string operations in the attribute @Value, I would consider splitting all the information within that attribute into different attributes.

Comment: BTW, I posted this code before knowing that you posted yours. If you cannot make it work, tell me and I will rewrite it to your current code.

Comment: Just two questions:
1. What are you going to do with the sum of the values? Because in the XSLT that you posted I cannot see where the result gets printed.
2. Are you using an XSLT processor which supports the node-set extension function?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the XPath function sum(), it is available in both XPath 2.0 for XSLT 2.0 and XPath 1.0 for XSLT 1.0 as described in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum. If the numbers you want to get the sum of are attributes "Value" to an element "Entry" use sum(//Entry/@Value)" to grab all and sum up. Change this to get the 10 elements you want in your xml data.

Comment: are you sure? sum doesn't sum all attributes together.That's why recursion is come to play. If it is as element node , then we can use sum. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: @pottuamman: Yes, I tried and the sum function worked on attributes - but only if the function can grab them from an nodelist (even attributes are technically nodes). Meanwhile I realized that the data you try to sum is only part of the attribute string, so you do some unwrapping with "substring". Because then there is no nodelist that sum can work on, it will fail. Try to split the information into its own attribute. You can do a preparing XSL-Transformation to get the proper hierarchy and do your sum on that.